# How to add a noise in vector?

Tags: r, vector

This is my question:
In one command, create a vector x in R that has 30 values going from 1 to 4 by 1/3 three times. In a second command, create a variable y that is a function of x as follows: 5 + x + 4*x^2. Add a vector of noise drawn from N(0,9) to y.
I have finished the first and second command, and I had a problem adding a noise? to the vector. Can someone show me how?

```
x <- seq(from = 1, to = 4, length = 30)
y <- 5 + x + 4*x^2
jitter(y, factor = 9, amount = NULL)
```

Comment: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822)

Comment: Take a look at the `rnorm` function, you can do `?rnorm`.

Comment: Like this `rnorm(y, 0, 9) + y`?